# Titan: what's the difference between lock expiry-time and wait-time?

Tags: titan

In the [documentation of Titan 1.0,](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/titan-config-ref.html#_storage_lock) I found these two configuration parameters that their description is identical and yet their defualt values are different.

```
 storage.lock.expiry-time
     Number of milliseconds the system waits for a lock application to be acknowledged by the storage backend
     Duration
     300000 ms
     GLOBAL_OFFLINE
```

and

```
storage.lock.wait-time
     Number of milliseconds the system waits for a lock application to be acknowledged by the storage backend
    Duration
    100 ms
    GLOBAL_OFFLINE
```

Is that a typo? Which one should I change to avoid `Lock expired.` issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good catch. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/1.0.0/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/graphdb/configuration/GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java#L573-L592), it appears to have been a copy and paste error.

> `storage.lock.expiry-time` Number of milliseconds after which a lock is considered to have expired. Lock applications that were not released are considered expired after this time and released. This value should be larger than the maximum time a transaction can take in order to guarantee that no correctly held applications are expired pre-maturely and as small as possible to avoid dead lock.
>
> `storage.lock.wait-time` The number of milliseconds the system waits for a lock application to be acknowledged by the storage backend. Also, the time waited at the end of all lock applications before verifying that the applications were successful. This value should be a small multiple of the average consistent write time.